# Can't use 3rd party components with Vue JS as CDN

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm learning Vue JS to try to make my django app more interactive,
and I'm going for the approach of using Vue JS as components in my templates, not as SPA.
it's like of JQuery replacement,
because of that I'm using CDN version by a script tag at the end of my body element.

the problem I'm facing is when I try to use 3rd party components I find most of them require npm installation, and I'm not pretty sure if I want to do that, I'd prefer to keep things simple,

so I'm trying to use 3rd party components with CDNs, like this one 
https://github.com/bliblidotcom/vue-rangedate-picker

but I don't know how to configure my current components to use it !

To give you an idea of what I'm trying to do here,
I have a component that handles a search form and displays data into table, 
and I want to add datepicker inside my search form and bind the dates to be passes as parameters in my API calls.

Comment: https://github.com/bliblidotcom/vue-rangedate-picker#browser and https://bliblidotcom.github.io/vue-rangedate-picker/demo/src/main.js

Comment: do I need to define a Vue component named 'rangedate-picker' to make it work ?
then I can use this component inside my current ones and exchange data ?
or is there a way to have it inside my current components directly ?
@Bert

Comment: In the second link above is a line, `VueRangedatePicker.default.install(Vue)`. That creates a global component called `vue-daterange-picker`.

Comment: @Bert, when I use that, it logs and error : Uncaught ReferenceError: VueRangedatePicker is not defined

Comment: Here is a complete working version lifted straight from the documentation and demo. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/qKywgV

Comment: Thanks A lot, when I used minified version of the component the error disappeared,

Comment: Thanks a lot it works perfectly, so what if the component doesn't support CDN, can I find a way to download it locally and use it with script tag as well ? @Bert

Comment: You're at the mercy of the library developer. Sometimes they give you just a .vue file (which you would have to compile) and sometimes they give you a dist folder you can use. Best bet is to read through the docs and look through any demos they have created to see how *they* do it.

Comment: Thanks man !, you're the best, I wish I could award you the answer, any way how did you figure out the .min.js link, because there link don't redirect to that version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the component is a bit incorrect. The browser CDN link will not work - you need the `/dist` file. Here is a minimal working demo.

Assuming you have also include `Vue` from a CDN, you can do it like this

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-rangedate-picker/dist/vue-rangedate-picker.min.js">
</script>

<div id="app">
  <vue-rangedate-picker 
    @selected="onDateSelected" i18n="EN" format="YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss">
  </vue-rangedate-picker>
</div>
</body>

<script>
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  VueRangedatePicker.default.install(Vue)

  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    methods: {
      onDateSelected() {
      }
    }
  })
})
</script>
</html>
```

Edit: PR fixing this in the docs [here](https://github.com/bliblidotcom/vue-rangedate-picker/pull/62).